# How to assign geometry type "polygons" to SpatVector with "null" geometry type using the terra package in R?

Tags: r, gis, spatial, terra

I have a series with shapefiles (not created by me) that I want to merge together. I am opening them with the `terra` package in R as a list of SpatVectors. However, when I try to merge them, I get the following error message:

```
Error: [vect] all SpatVectors must have the same geometry type
```

I found out (by running `geomtype()`) that one of my SpatVectors has geometry type `"null"`, while the other ones are `"polygons"`. How can I assign the same geometry type ("polygons") to the SpatVector without one?

I have tried the below, but none of them worked:

```
null_geometry_type_SpatVector <- 
    vect("null_geometry_type_SpatVector.shp", type="polygons")
```

```
geomtype(null_geometry_type_SpatVector) <- 
   geomtype(polygons_geometry_type_SpatVector)
```

Where `polygons_geometry_type_SpatVector` refers to a SpatVector I have with the correct geometry type.

```
geomtype(null_geometry_type_SpatVector) <- "polygons"
```

UPDATE:

Following an answer below, I have tried:

```
i <- emptyGeoms(null_geometry_type_SpatVector)
null_geometry_type_SpatVector_cleaned <- null_geometry_type_SpatVector[!i]
```

The commands run, but I am not sure what to do next. My goal is to be able to merge `null_geometry_type_SpatVector` with the other SpatVectors I have in my list (each SpatVector is a county in the US and merged together they form a state). So I believe I have to assign geometry type `"polygons"` to `null_geometry_type_SpatVector_cleaned` so I am able to merge it with the other SpatVectors and plot the merged SpatVector, but I still don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

UPDATE 2:

The file that I am using that had NULL geometry is this [one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ci_NQkNnpgcAY8CPfnkEKWXm981QmzJD/view?usp=share_link).

Comment: You should now be able to continue with `null_geometry_type_SpatVector_cleaned`? You cannot assign the geometry type like you are trying to do. There are ways, but we need an example. I do not know how to create a NULL geometry. Can you share an example file that creates a null geometry?

Comment: @RobertHijmans , I am unable to continue with `null_geometry_type_SpatVector_cleaned`. I am not sure how to replicate my issue by creating a file (I will keep trying and post here if I have success), but I can share the file that is giving me a hard time. As I mentioned in the beginning of my question, I am working with shapefiles generated by other parties. I will post the link to the file as another update in my question.

Comment: Thanks but can you please share in a way that does not require a login?

Comment: @RobertHijmans , I changed the link, I believe you won't need to login now to download it.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have expanded my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing an example file. With that file, I get

```
x <- vect("clu_public_a_ne165.shp")
geomtype(x)
#[1] "null"
```

You can fix that with

```
x <- na.omit(x, geom=TRUE)

geomtype(x)
#[1] "polygons"
```

Or with

```
x <- vect("clu_public_a_ne165.shp")
i <- emptyGeoms(x)
x <- x[-i]

geomtype(x)
#[1] "polygons"
```

And then proceed with `x`.

This does mean that you lose the records that do not have an associated geometry.

If you do not want that to happen, you can use the terra 1.7-32. This is currently the development version that you can install with

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

With that version you should not get an error message at all when you use `rbind` (that is what I assume you are using).

Comment: Thanks ! I have updated my question after I implemented your suggestions (I focus on the second one), but I still don't know how to assign the polygons geometry type to the SpatVector with NULL geometry. Let me know if my update is not clear, but a follow-up would be appreciated!